# Prove: existence of solution of $Ax = b$ by least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying for my exam of linear algebra.. I want to prove the following corollary:

> Given $A \in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, there is always a solution $x$ to $Ax = y$ for the least-squares minimization problem, if and only if $A$ has rank $n$ (full column rank).

Comment: This seems strange. We usually resort to least squares when we have more equations than unknowns, that's more rows than columns, that's $m\gt n$, in which case $A$ *can't* have rank $m$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah my bad rank (A) = n

Comment: So that would be full *column* rank, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's right, right now I edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do least squares is, you solve the *normal equation*,  $A^tAx=A^ty$. Note that $A^tA$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. If the rank of $A$ is less than $n$, then the rank of $A^tA$ is less than $n$, so there are vectors $y$ not in its column space, so there are vectors $y$ for which the normal equation has no solution. If $A$ has rank $n$, then (you can prove that) $A^tA$ has rank $n$, so the normal equation has a solution for all $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem
$$
\|Ax-y\|=\min
$$
for any given $A$ and $y$ has always *a* solution $x$ since the system of normal equations $A^TAx=A^Ty$ is solvable for any $y$. Any $\tilde{x}=x+z$, where $z\in\ker A$, is again *a* solution. If $A$ has a full column rank and hence $\dim\ker A=0$, then the problem has *the* solution, that is, *a* solution which is *unique*.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how can we prove that $A^TAx = A^Tb$ always has a solution for any $A, b$? If $A$ has full rank and has more rows than columns, then I know that $A^TA$ is invertible. But what about the other cases?

Comment: @Blue $By=c$ has a solution if and only if $c\in R(B)$. We have  $A^Tb\in R(A^T)=R(A^TA)$ (where $R$ denotes the range of the matrix).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is clear that $R(A^TA) \subseteq R(A^T)$, but why is the other direction true?