# Least Square Methods

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We know from linear algebra, the least square solution of linear equation system :
$$Ax=b$$ always exists. That is, the equation
$$A^TAx=A^Tb$$ always has at least one solution.
$\bar x$ is the solution of the equation. I want to prove that $\forall r \in\mathbb R^n$
$$\|A \bar x - b\|_2 \leq \|Ar - b\|_2$$
Any hints on how to approach this problem would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/prove-existence-of-solution-of-ax-b-by-least-squares?rq=1).

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
Ar-b & = (Ar-A\overline x) + (A\overline x - b) \\ {} \\
\|Ar-b\|^2 & = \|Ar-A\overline x\|^2 + (Ar-A\overline x)\cdot(A\overline x - b) + \|A\overline x-b\|^2.
\end{align}
$$
Can you show that the dot-product is zero? $\qquad$

Comment: I am not sure how to, is there something orthogonal that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. The least squares solution $\bar{x}$ solves the problem
$$\min_{r\in \mathbb{R}^n}\|Ar-b\|^2_2$$
Indeed
$$\|Ar-b\|^2_2=(Ar-b)^T(Ar-b)=r^TA^TAr-r^TA^Tb-b^TAr+b^Tb=r^TA^TAr-2r^TA^Tb+b^Tb$$
By taking the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) with respect to $r$ and setting it equal to zero we obtain
$$2A^TAr-2A^Tb=0$$
$$\bar{x}=r^*=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$
Therefore
$$\|A\bar{x}-b\|^2_2\leq\|Ar-b\|^2_2, \ \forall r \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

Comment: You took the derivative wrt r, but we don't know if the value $\ bar x$ is minimum or maximum. In order to determine minimum or maximum, we should also take a second-order derivative, right?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483339/proof-of-convexity-of-linear-least-squares)